# Google Maps and Short Code Tabs in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, shortcode

I've having an issue with Google maps not centering on the pin. See an example of the issue here: http://www.heyheygorgeous.com/enzocoboston/test

You'll see that if the google map is placed in the first tab, it works. Click on the other tabs and the google map doesn't center on the pin.

Please let us know what to do to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the google map to work inside a hidden tab, try setting the iframe width of the google map to 100% instead of using a px width. Example: width="100% height="350"

If you're using wordpress, just grap an iframe plugin, otherwise WP will erase the  tags when you switch between VISUAL and HTML views.

You can see an example here: [Fairmont Scottsdale Princess](http://azgolfpass.com/resorts/scottsdale-princess/) (click "map")